# Rating not updated on actions on google

Tags: actions-on-google

My action is showing 0.0 rating even after six 5.0 ratings by my friends.
Also, measure usage shows "No Data to display". What shall I do?

Answer (score 2):

Google Assistant Projects data update within 24 hours

> Once you've published a version of your Actions project, you'll start seeing analytics data in the Actions console within 24 hours. These analytics provide information about usage, health, and discovery.

Source: https://developers.google.com/actions/console/analytics